# python.net import clr throws invalid pointer error

Tags: python, linux, mono, ubuntu-14.04, python.net

When i am trying to import clr in my python code i get the following error:

```
*** Error in `python': free(): invalid pointer: 0xb0f1a120 ***
Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Python.Runtime.Runtime.Py_Initialize () <0xffffffff>
  at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Initialize () <0x00023>
  at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize () <0x00047>
  at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.InitExt () <0x0000b>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0xcb5f4) [0xb1b5e5f4]
    [0xb7745d14]
    [0xb7745d1e]
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x47) [0xb7592607]
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x143) [0xb7595a33]
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x68e53) [0xb75cce53]
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7333a) [0xb75d733a]
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x73fad) [0xb75d7fad]
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so(PyString_InternInPlace+0x97) [0xb0b3a157]
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so(PyString_InternFromString+0x2f) [0xb0ad78ef]
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so(PyType_Ready+0xb50) [0xb0b356e0]
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so(_Py_ReadyTypes+0xcd) [0xb0b3d47d]
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so(Py_InitializeEx+0x6d) [0xb0b5d5dd]
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so(Py_Initialize+0x1b) [0xb0b5df7b]
    [0xb481553c]
    [0xb4814f2c]
    [0xb480af98]
    [0xb480ae84]
    [0xb480af0d]
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0x29723) [0xb1abc723]

Debug info from gdb:

Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No threads.

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

I found a reference to a similar problem (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2014-October/001598.html) but i can not figure out how to use the npython binary for example and i do not wish to rebuild python with shared-library enabled.

Any hints or help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some painful trials i achieved using `import clr` successfully in my code.

First i needed somehow to use the right binaries and in order to achieve that i used the latest development source from git of the pythonnet/pythonnet package.

You can try: `$ sudo pip install --pre pythonnet` that downloads and installs the latest development source. But keep in mind there are some perquisites so i am attaching the travis build details

```
system_info
Build language: python
Operating System:   Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
$ python --version
Python 2.7.9
$ pip --version
pip 6.0.7 from /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe"
$ sudo apt-get -qq install mono-devel mono-gmcs mono-xbuild nunit-console
$ sudo mozroots --import --machine --sync
$ yes | sudo certmgr -ssl -m https://go.microsoft.com
$ yes | sudo certmgr -ssl -m https://nugetgallery.blob.core.windows.net
$ yes | sudo certmgr -ssl -m https://nuget.org
$ pip install six
```

Now normally installing pythonnet with pip should execute successfully and you can try calling import clr in your python code.  In my case personally it failed even in this scenario although it was installing without errors. The reason was that although my python was compiled without --enable-shared, running

```
$ python -c 'import sys; from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_var; print(get_config_var("Py_ENABLE_SHARED"))'
```

returned 1 although it should return 0.

So i downloaded the latest dev-source from git https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

and after putting it in the right folder i edited setup.py setting the variable 
 that was checking for the shared libraries to 0, after that executing

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

the script installed successfully without error and i could use import clr in my python scripts. To make sure everything runs correctly you can run:

```
$ python src/tests/runtests.py
```

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, this is addressed in [Pythonnet issue #119](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/119)

adding ...

```
defines.append("PYTHON_WITHOUT_ENABLE_SHARED")
```

... to `setup.py` and then installing using `python setup.py install [options]` achieves the same effect as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31879840/1020470).